# Activating / clicking a browser extension in Firefox with Selenium in Python 3

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, browser, firefox-addon

I am writing a script for web automation with SELENIUM and, in theory, I have two options to capture the data I need from the websites I am scraping:

- I can let the script extract relevant information from each tag on the result pages.
- I can make the script click on the browser extension button in my browser window and let the extension manage the data for me.

I know how to extract information by HTML tag, but when it comes to browser extensions, I have only found instructions how to install / uninstall them with SELENIUM, but no instructions how to "activate" them once they are installed.

I am using Firefox and would be very grateful if you could point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to solve this problem in FIREFOX but in CHROME:

- I created a browser profile including my extension and a key shortcut to activate it.
- I opened that profile when starting the browser with SELENIUM.
- I used SELENIUM to navigate to the right URL.
- I used [pyautogui](https://pypi.org/project/PyAutoGUI/) to press the relevant keys and trigger the file download.